# My ReadyNAS 214 wont shutdown -> do_exit+8c4

Tags: shutdown, readynas

I have a problem with my Netgear RN214 NAS. It`s not shutting down properly. It makes no difference if I do it from the webgui nor with the power bottom. After a few seconds it shows "do_exit+8c4" on the display and nothing happens after that.
Currently have the newest firmware installed -> 6.4.2. I have read a few posts about this issue but the only "solution" was to change the bond mode from LACP (which I had also configured) to ALB or TLB. Now I have changed my mode to ALB the same message accured on the display.

I don' t know what to do. I also found nothing in the webgui logs nor system logs (with ssh).  Can anyone can get me a hand?

Comment: What did Netgear support say about this?

Comment: I didn't ask the support.

Comment: Vendor support should always be your first reference. Server Fault isn't "tech support for the Internet". I'd recommend you check with them, as they are experts on their systems.

Comment: That' s right. I simply hadn't thought of that. I will ask them. Thank you!